# Can google crawl a page with dynamic "load more" button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-crawler

When the user gets to the end of my page, there is a load more button. It uses jQuery ajax to load more data.

Will google be able to spider this dynamic content?
If not, then how can I make this content crawlable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

> Today, as long as you're not blocking Googlebot from crawling your JavaScript or CSS files, we are generally able to render and understand your web pages like modern browsers.

https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2015/10/deprecating-our-ajax-crawling-scheme.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, depending on the version of the bot. Bots can submit forums and click elements. If the bot trusts your javascript, it will load it.

Comment: Can you please verify this with documentation please? According to Moz this isnt the case: https://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo/basics-of-search-engine-friendly-design-and-development

Answer (score 0):

This effect is known as **infinite scroll** and whether it gets crawled by search engines depends on both how it's implemented and the capabilities of the search engine.

It's fair to say Google can often handle AJAX, but there are other search engines and not all of them can so it's probably prudent to build it in such a way that it falls back to regular pagination.

If you build it with regular pagination and then enhance it with Javascript to produce the infinite scroll, then it will still work without Javascript. [Paul Irish's Infinite Scroll](https://github.com/infinite-scroll/infinite-scroll) does this, but it's no longer maintained so I can't really recommend it. There are some excellent demos at https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/.